# new ports iis 7.5 configuring intranet

Tags: windows, iis, configuration, intranet, ports

I am trying to set up an intranet on iis 7.5 Windows 8. I have two new ports in the HOSTS file and in Services and IIS manager sets up the website names with the port numbers and starts the service. (I am not using www by the way just http://domainname.com) The firewall is disabled. IE finds localhost perfectly, but will not serve the two Domains I have set up, with or without the port numbers. Nor will it do so if I change the port to 80. Is there a configuration procedure that is taken for granted? can anyone offer advice please? My document directories contain a file index.html just for testing

I've added some comments below, still no resolution

Comment: the binding option is blank in all domains including localhost in the site bindings page in iis manager

Comment: the site bindings page for http, hostname, port, default ip address and on edit does not allow you to change binding info

Comment: I've looked at all the iis configuration options and there seems to be no difference between those settings for any of the domains ie localhost and otherwise. Do my directories need special permissions? The adhoc directory for localhost doesn't have any.

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup your IIS Bind? I only ask because you didn't mention the BIND settings?  You should be able to setup your host header, and the port you should like IIS to listen.  Probably not your solution but just wanted to make sure.